# Pandas DataFrame take automatically wrong value as index

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to create DataFrames from a JSON file.

I have a list named "Series_participants" containing a part of this JSON file. My list look like thise when i print it.

```
participantId                                                                1
championId                                                                  76
stats                        {'item0': 3265, 'item2': 3143, 'totalUnitsHeal...
teamId                                                                     100
timeline                     {'participantId': 1, 'csDiffPerMinDeltas': {'1...
spell1Id                                                                     4
spell2Id                                                                    12
highestAchievedSeasonTier                                               SILVER
dtype: object
<class 'list'>
```

After i tri to convert this list to a DataFrame like this

```
pd.DataFrame(Series_participants)
```

But pandas use values of "stats" and "timeline" as index for the DataFrame. I expected to have automatic index range (0, ..., n)

EDIT 1:

```
   participantId    championId     stats  teamId    timeline    spell1Id  spell2Id  highestAchievedSeasonTier
0       1               76         3265     100       NaN          4          12     SILVER
```

I want to have a dataframe with "stats" & "timeline" colomns containing dicts of their values as in the Series display.

What is my error ?

EDIT 2:

I have tried to create manually the DataFrame but pandas didn't take my choices in consideration and finally take indexes of "stats" key of the Series.

here is my code :

```
for j in range(0,len(df.participants[0])):

    for i in range(0,len(df.participants[0][0])):

        Series_participants = pd.Series(df.participants[0][i])
        test = {'participantId':Series_participants.values[0],'championId':Series_participants.values[1],'stats':Series_participants.values[2],'teamId':Series_participants.values[3],'timeline':Series_participants.values[4],'spell1Id':Series_participants.values[5],'spell2Id':Series_participants.values[6],'highestAchievedSeasonTier':Series_participants.values[7]}

        if j == 0:
            df_participants = pd.DataFrame(test)

        else:
            df_participants.append(test, ignore_index=True)
```

The double loop is to parse all "participant" of my JSON file.

LAST EDIT :

I achieved what i wanted with the following code :

```
for i in range(0,len(df.participants[0])):

    Series_participants = pd.Series(df.participants[0][i])

    df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=[Series_participants.values], columns=['participantId','championId','stats','teamId','timeline','spell1Id','spell2Id','highestAchievedSeasonTier'])

    if i == 0:
        df_participants = pd.DataFrame(df_test)
    else:
        df_participants = df_participants.append(df_test, ignore_index=True)

print(df_participants)
```

Thanks to all for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency, you should try and manipulate your data *as you construct* your dataframe rather than as a separate step.

However, to split apart your dictionary keys and values you can use a combination of `numpy.repeat` and `itertools.chain`. Here's a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2],
                   'B': [{'key1': 'val0', 'key2': 'val9'},
                         {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}],
                   'C': [{'key3': 'val10', 'key4': 'val8'},
                         {'key3': 'val3', 'key4': 'val4'}]})

import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

chainer = chain.from_iterable

lens = df['B'].map(len)

res = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.repeat(df['A'], lens),
                    'B': list(chainer(df['B'].map(lambda x: x.values())))})

res.index = chainer(df['B'].map(lambda x: x.keys()))

print(res)

      A     B
key1  1  val0
key2  1  val9
key1  2  val1
key2  2  val2
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated per comments: Pandas data frames can hold dictionaries, but it is not recommended.

Pandas is interpreting that you want one index for each of the your dictionary keys and then broadcasting the single item columns across them.

So to help with what you are trying to do I would recommend reading in your dictionaries items as columns. Which is what data frames are typically used for and very good at.

Example Error due to pandas trying to read in the dictionary by key, value pair:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['a', 'b'], index=['a', 'b'])
df.loc['a','a'] = {'apple': 2}
```

returns

```
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

Per jpp in the comments below (When using the constructor method):

"They can hold arbitrary types, e.g.

```
df.iat[0, 0] = {'apple': 2}
```

However, it's not recommended to use Pandas in this way."

Comment: `df['a','a']` is iillegal in python.

Comment: Good catch... too early... don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: `I do not believe that pandas dataframes can hold dictionaries.` Not true. They can hold arbitrary types, e.g. `df.iat[0, 0] = {'apple': 2}`. However, it's *not recommended* to use Pandas in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to input lists, series or arrays containing dicts into the object constructor, it doesn't recognise what you're trying to do. One way around this is manually setting:

```
df.at['a', 'b'] = {'x':value}
```

Note, the above will only work if the columns **and** indexes are already created in your DataFrame.